# Sending TCP packets over internet (using Ruby)

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to learn how to send TCP packets across the internet to another computer.  So say, computer 1 sends data across the internet to computer 2 (using TCP).  Assuming that both computer have port forwarding correctly set, how would I go about establishing a TCP connection between the two computers (in Ruby preferably)?  I have it working on my LAN, but when I try over the internet, it doesn't seem to work.

My attempt (basically):

Computer 1:

```
server = TCPServer.new 32500
client = server.accept
```

Computer 2:

```
TCPSocket.new PUBLIC_IP_OF_COMPUTER_1, 32500
```

Problem is that TCPSocket never connects to TCPServer.

I read in the Ruby doc that TCPServer.new's syntax is

```
new(remote_host, remote_port, local_host=nil, local_port=nil)
```

What happens if I just leave local_host=nil and local_port=nil (rather than assign them the private IP and port 32500 number on Computer 1)?

If somebody could point me in the right direction, that's be great!  I hope I my approach is at least somewhat correct.

Comment: http://workingwithtcpsockets.com/ a mustread for you, it is is about networking with ruby

Answer (score 1):

You created a server which is listening only on the loopback Interface.

Try this out:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

You will get your external IP address, how it is visible from outside, for example 123.123.123.123

```
server = TCPServer.new 2000
```

Now You have a server listening on port 2000

```
lsof -i :2000
```

for example:

> ruby    37186 wopi    6u  IPv4 0xcf0818acc2bdc38d      0t0  TCP *:callbook (LISTEN)

now connect from THE SAME machine to localhost

```
telnet localhost 2000
```

this works

```
telnet 123.123.123.123 2000 # substitute your real external IP address
```

this will not work

That is why You can't connect from outside.

Checkout how ngrep, netcat and tcpdump are working, invaluable tools for network debugging.

Comment: Hi, do you know where I could find more documentation on this stuff?  For example, Ruby doesn't seem to have a class called Curl, and is it possible to use a TCPSocket rather than telnet?

Comment: curl is a binary, you enter it in the bash/zsh shell, not in the ruby console, same as telnet, netcat, and lsof in my post. You have ruby bindings for curl, called curb, but this is another story, not relevant for you yet.

Comment: You can use netcat pretty well to play with coumunication over network (telnet too), but this is a binary, not a ruby library. Check out the book I have posted in the command above, when You want do networking stuff with ruby.